# Sending recurring mail in background in every ten minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hangfire, hangfire-autofac

I want to send mail to admin in every ten minutes after the application has started. Simple recurring tasks has been running. But when I try to send mail, I get "Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException". Here is what I have done.

I have created a middleware "SchedularMiddleware" and used it like in my Configure method in startup.cs

```
 app.UseSchedularMiddleware();
```

And here is the SchedularMiddleware

```
public class SchedularMiddleware : Controller
{
   private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

   public SchedularMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ISendEmailService sendEmailService)
   {
      _next = next;
      sendEmailService.SendMail("wayne@gmail.com");
   }
   public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   {           
      await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
   }
}
```

And here is the implementation of Service

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => SendMail(), Cron.MinuteInterval(5));
```

This simple task is running but when I try to send mail I get error.

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine("manchester derby!"), Cron.MinuteInterval(1));
```

Here is the stack trace of the error.

```
Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'Demo.Module.Schedular.Services.SendEmailService' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
```

Comment: have you register `ISendEmailService `service with autofac? this error seems to tell `ISendEmailService ` is not registered with autofac

Comment: I have registered these services through IServiceProvider

Comment: You're using `asp.net core` right? add `builder.RegisterType<SendEmailService>().As<ISendEmailService >();` In the ConfigureServices method of your Startup class or anywhere else where you are registering your other dependencies if it does not resolve your problem show us your startup.cs class

Comment: Yeah I am using dot net core! Here is what I have done. I have static class like IServiceCollection AddFrameworkServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationRoot configuration){} where I resgister my services like services.Add(). Then in my ConfigureServices of Startup.cs, I include it like  services.AddFrameworkServices(Configuration);

Comment: Ok that i can understand but did you put `builder.RegisterType<SendEmailService>().As<ISendEmailServic‌​e >();` this? if you want to know more about dependency registries using autofac read [this](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#controllers-as-services) document as well